# Pointwise convergence of $f_n(x) = 1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

**Problem:**

Let $f_n(x) = 1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n$.

Show that $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges pointwise towards $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ on $(-1, 1)$.

**My attempt:**

Sadly, I've been unable to start. The chapter in my book talks about integration and differentiation of series of functions, but I haven't been able to link this to any method for solving this particular problem. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you prove the partial summation formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A geometric series sum is $$f(x)=1+x+\cdots+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$ when $x\in (-1,1)$ we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}x^n=0$ thus the result

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$$ You can show this by multiplying $(1-x)(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})$. Now, if $|x|<1$, what do you know about $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n$?